# IOS TableView multi Select by section

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am currently developing an app for iPhone and i have a spent time looking at how to select multiple rows in a table view however the answers i found did not include groups. I have a table as seen below with two groups one for client selection and the other for navigation links i would like to display the selected item for both groups rather than the entire table but i have had no luck finding any answers for this.

i understand you check can what section the row is in but i am not sure how to implement this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Additionally i do know how to select rows by changing the cell style depending on if it has been selected or not but its doing this for two groups im stuck on. Again thank you for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code to allow for multiple selection:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
}
```

Perhaps you are looking for something like this to execute code based on which section the selection is in:

```
#define CLIENT_SECTION 0
#define MENU_SECTION 1
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == CLIENT_SECTION) {
        // execute code
    } else if (indexPath.section == MENU_SECTION) {
        // execute code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[myTable setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
[[myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
else
{
[[myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}

}
```